# Why does Exodus 3 refer to "the angel of the LORD"?

Tags: exodus

Exodus 3:2 ([ESV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=exodus%203&version=ESV;WLC)):

> And the angel of the LORD (*malʾak yhwh*) appeared to [Moses] in a flame of fire out of the midst of a bush.

It seems pretty clear from what follows that the individual in the bush is YHWH himself.<sup>1</sup>

> When the LORD saw that he turned aside to see, God called to him out of the bush....

[Some have suggested](https://books.google.com/books?id=8H9E00e5PSwC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA110#v=onepage&q&f=false) that rather that "the angel of the LORD", we ought to think of "the angel" as being [in apposition](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Gesenius%27_Hebrew_Grammar/130._Wider_Use_of_the_Construct_State#GHGpar-130-e) to "YHWH" (i.e., the latter is a restatement of the former — "the angel that is YHWH").

- Is "the angel of the LORD" indeed referring to YHWH himself?
- If so, what is the point of describing him initially as "the angel of the LORD”?

---

<sub>1. This seems clear to me anyway. [Another question about the same verse](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/15594/3555) is predicated on a different understanding, and the answers I looked through agree with the question.</sub>

Comment: A [few](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/19782/sandals-and-holy-ground) other [related](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/19769/who-is-speaking-the-angel-or-jesus-in-revelation-228-16/19772#19772) qustions

Comment: As I say in my answer to the other question you referenced in your footnote,  I'm not sure we have grounds to conclude that God was in the bush.  God's voice comes from the bush. That is all we are told.  It very well may have been an angel there in person for Moses to see but then God speaking directly.

Comment: Exodus 3:6 ...Moses hid his face, because he was afraid to look *at God*. Either God was in that bush, that bush was some kind of spiritual window, or we are given an account of Moses' blunder in thinking God was in the bush. Seems reasonable that God was in the bush.

Answer (score 10):

Frequently, an "Angel of the LORD" will appear in passages throughout the Bible to bring a message to an individual. In these instances, the speech used is always that of God himself. Tradition held that messages came with the full authority, weight, and force of the person who sent it. This messenger was an extension of the originator of the messenger himself, which is why (as Shakespeare said) you ["don't shoot the messenger".](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_the_messenger) In fact, the word "Angel" [can be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angel_of_the_Lord) and [often](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Judges+13%3A3&version=GW) [is](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Judges+13%3A3&version=NET) translated as "messenger".

The Hebrew and Aramaic Lexicon of the Old Testament defines the Hebrew word מַלְאָךְ as messenger:

> מַלְאָךְ: cs. מַלְאַךְ, sf. מַלְאָכוֹ, מַלְאָכִי; pl. מַלְאָכִים, cs. מַלְאֲכֵי, sf. מַלְאָכָיו: — 1. (of men) messenger: of Jacob Gn 32:4, 7 & oft.; ? business agent Is 23:2; — 2. God’s messenger(s), viz. a) prophet(s) Is 44:26, b) priest(s) Ma 2:7 (so hammal˒āk Ec 5:5); c) cosmic: the wind(s) Ps 104:4; — 3. heavenly messenger(s), angel(s): a) sg. Gn 48:16, mal˒ākô Gn 24:7; b) pl. Gn 19:1; c) spec. uses: mal˒ak habberît Ma 3:1 ϝ berît III 10; hammal˒āk hammašḥît bā˓ām 2S 24:16 & sim. expr., mal˒akê māwet Pr 16:14; d) oft. mal˒ak ˒elōhîm Gn 21:17, mal˒ak yhwh Gn 16:7.

Interestingly, our word for missions "Evangelism" derives from the Latin Evangelium - itself a derivation of the greek word for messenger/angel.

Messengers had a well-established tradition around them and in England for example, killing a town crier who was delivering a decree from a King (for example) could result in charges of treason since he came in the King's authority and was acting under official duty. As such, harming the crier (messenger) was an affront to the King himself which was treason. The [BBC states,](http://news.bbc.co.uk/local/bradford/hi/people_and_places/arts_and_culture/newsid_8931000/8931369.stm)

> Historically, town criers were the original newsmen, bringing the news to the people and acting as spokesmen for the King. Town criers were protected by law and "don't shoot the messenger" was a very real command. Anything that was done to a town crier was deemed to be done to the King and was seen as treason.

This tradition extended back much further and applied even to the divine realm. According to *[Canaan and Israel in Antiquity](https://books.google.com/books?id=hMeRK7B1EsMC&pg=PA187&dq=messengers+antiquity&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjk94aVmM_JAhVQ_WMKHYO0Btw4ChDoAQhEMAU#v=onepage&q=messengers%20antiquity&f=false)* by [Dr. Kurt L. Noll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurt_Noll),

> The divine realm, or pantheon, presupposed by ancient Near Eastern kings mirrored the hierarchy of the human social and political world. ... Many gods were messengers. The role of divine messenger was essential because ancient patron gods did not have cell phones or email. In the greek language, a messenger is called an angelos, which is translated into English as an 'angel'. Although later Christian doctrine tried to demote angels from the status of gods by claiming that angels had been created by the Christian god in reality an angel or divine messenger was a common minor god in every ancient Near Eastern religion, including Judaism and earliest Christianity. Some early Christians even identified Jesus as an angel of their god.

In the Iliad and Oddesy, quite a bit of messaging occurs. *[In Between Orality and Luteracy: Communication and Adaptation in Antiquity](https://books.google.com/books?id=n0z3AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA29&dq=messengers+antiquity&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-2KGEmM_JAhUT0WMKHeNrBYcQ6AEISjAG#v=onepage&q=messengers%20antiquity&f=false)* Dr. [Jonathan L. Ready](http://classics.indiana.edu/faculty/ready.shtml) discusses this classic work stating,

> ...Homer's gods and mortals both transmit messages via messengers...Although Zeus's worry about a false messenger reveals some anxiety about these agents, Homeric characters generally trust messengers to pass on messages faithfully. This confidence reflects the characters' view that with power comes the ability to control another's action and speech.

In [John Durham's commentary](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0849902029) on Exodus, he notes

> he messenger of Yahweh, מַלְאַךְ יהוה, is not an “angel” in the sense in which “angel” is now generally understood. As often in the OT (Gen 18, Judg 6), there is in this passage a fluid interchange between symbol, representative, and God himself.

A similar scene to that of Exodus 3:2 occurs in [Revelation 22:8-16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation+22%3A8-16&version=NET).  In verse 8-9 it states that John

> threw [himself] down to worship at the feet of the angel who was showing them to me. But he said to [John], “Do not do this! I am a fellow servant with you and with your brothers the prophets, and with those who obey the words of this book. Worship God!”

Yet only a few verses later in 12 and 13, the Angel says

> (Look! **I am coming soon,** and my reward is with me to pay each one according to what he has done! **I am the Alpha and the Omega**, the first and the last, the beginning and the end!)

So an Angel of the LORD appearing and speaking as God is not an altogether uncommon occurrence. [There are numerous other examples,](https://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?quicksearch=%22angel+of+the+lord%22&qs_version=NIV) but in short, It is God speaking, but through his vessel, his messenger, the Angel of the LORD who is delivering the message to Moses.

Thus, when the messenger states that he is the LORD and that he is God, the messenger is not making a claim, he is simply reciting and delivering the message. This makes sense in terms of messaging in antiquity in which the messenger would read a letter or recite a memorized speech which would often be from the first person perspective of the messages' author. We are not to understand that the angel/messenger himself is God, but that the one who spoke the message is God. This is why the angel/messenger refuses worship in the passage in Revelation - it is inappropriate to worship him because he is not God, merely his messenger.

The same would be true of an earthly messenger - the audience members would understand that the messenger was not the king himself - though he might state that he is while discharging his duties (reading the message) - but merely that he comes with the authority of and under the direction of the king.

Comment: "This is why the angel refuses worship in the passage in Revelation" — though the angel [in Joshua 5](http://www.esvbible.org/joshua5.14-15/) does not refuse worship. [I don't personally think](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/24241/1619) you can be that precise.

Comment: Joshua 5 doesn't actually use the term "Angel of the LORD" It just says "a man" who identifies himself as commander of the armies of Israel.

Comment: I have some trouble using Revelation to interpret Exodus like this. The differences in time, language, and genre are so vast, and the shifts in man’s understanding of how God and his host interact so great...

Comment: True, but nevertheless he identifies himself as belonging to the Lord, but not the person of the Lord himself, and yet receives worship, which is why your "…it is inappropriate to worship him because he is not God…" seems to be too certain. In the right context, an angel or agent of the Lord is so closely identified with the Lord himself that worship of one appears to be equivilent to worship of the other.

Comment: What is more curious to me is that in some instances, the Angel want's the  [message recipient to take off his sandals](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/19782/sandals-and-holy-ground) because he is standing on holy ground, yet in other cases (most cases) he could care less. It's almost as if the messenger is embued with additional power in some cases, but not others.

Comment: `"Evangelism" derives from the Latin Evangelium - Latin for messenger/angel.`: [*Evangelium*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Devangelium) is the word for “gospel” (Gr. εὐαγγέλιον). Latin angel = [*angelus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dangelus) (=ἄγγελος). Both of these are derived from the Greek ἀγγέλλω = to announce, but different words.

Comment: My larger problem is that here the text does indeed say "**God** called to him out of the bush” so the way I read it either there were two separate individuals both present or they’re one and the same. I don’t follow how it works to interpret this as the speech being that of the angel acting as messenger ("We are not to understand that the angel/messenger himself is God....”).

Answer (score 0):

Most scholars acknowledge that The angel of the Lord usually refers to God Himself, but we always need to look at the context to determine if he is just an “angelic” messenger, or if He is God Himself in a visible form.

Exodus 3:2-6

> <sup>**2**</sup> And the angel of the Lord appeared to him in a flame of fire out of the midst of a bush. He looked, and behold, the bush was burning, yet it was not consumed. <sup>**3**</sup> And Moses said, “I will turn aside to see this great sight, why the bush is not burned.” <sup>**4**</sup> When the Lord saw that he turned aside to see, God called to him out of the bush, “Moses, Moses!” And he said, “Here I am.” <sup>**5**</sup> Then he said, “Do not come near; take your sandals off your feet, for the place on which you are standing is holy ground.” <sup>**6**</sup> And he said, “I am the God of your father, the God of Abraham, the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob.” And Moses hid his face, for he was afraid to look at God.

Here, the angel of the Lord is God. This is a theophany or an Old Testament appearance of the pre-incarnate Christ.

In John 8:56-59, Christ makes a statement to the Jewish religious leaders that He was and is deity. He is God!

> <sup>**56**</sup> Your father Abraham rejoiced that he would see my day. He saw it and was glad.” <sup>**57**</sup> So the Jews said to him, “You are not yet fifty years old, and have you seen Abraham?” <sup>**58**</sup> Jesus said to them, “Truly, truly, I say to you, before Abraham was, I am.” <sup>**59**</sup> So they picked up stones to throw at him, but Jesus hid himself and went out of the temple.”

The religious leaders understood Christ claimed to deity because He claimed to have existed at the time of Abraham and more importantly, He claimed the Name of YHWH, “I AM”, The leaders saw this as blasphemy which carried a penalty of death.  Many verses in Scripture teach that the “I AM” refers to our God and that there is no other God.
e.g.
Isaiah 41:4

> Who has performed and done this, calling the generations from the beginning? I, the Lord, the first, and with the last; I am he.

Isaiah 43:10

> “You are my witnesses,” declares the Lord, “and my servant whom I have chosen, that you may know and believe me and understand that I am he. Before me no god was formed, nor shall there be any after me. 11 I, I am the Lord, and besides me there is no savior. 12 I declared and saved and proclaimed, when there was no strange god among you; and you are my witnesses,” declares the Lord, “and I am God.”

Answer (score 0):

Jesus' own witness on this subject is important.

> And the Father himself, which hath sent me, hath borne witness of me.
> Ye have neither heard his voice **at any time,** nor seen his shape. (John
> 5:37, KJV)

That comes on the heels of John's statement, a few chapters prior, which is equally definitive.

> No man hath seen God **at any time**, the only begotten Son, which is in
> the bosom of the Father, he hath declared him. (John 1:18, KJV)

If no one has ever seen God "at any time," then we know for sure that Moses cannot have seen God--not at the burning bush, not on Mount Sinai, nor Mount Horeb.

The "angel of Yahweh" is not the same entity as "Yahweh."  As is widely known, "angel" means "messenger."  When a king speaks through a messenger, the messenger is not speaking of himself, but speaking the king's words.  Just the same, the messenger's hearers are not hearing the king's voice--only his words.

The same is true at the burning bush.  Moses is not seeing or hearing Yahweh, he is seeing and hearing Yahweh's messenger--the one who is sent from Yahweh.  But the words he hears are those of God, as spoken by the angel.

The text in Exodus says "angel of Yahweh" precisely because it was not Yahweh Himself whom Moses saw and heard.

Comment: You have one huge problem with your understanding as to the identity of the Angel of the Lord. Please read the following. https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/81857/why-does-the-angel-of-the-lord-say-you-have-not-withheld-your-son-from-me-in-ge/81862?noredirect=1#comment167813_81862 I go into 
 detail why the Angel of the Lord is the preincarnate Jesus Christ. Also read Malachi 3:1 and tell me who the malak/angel/messenger of the covenant is that will come to His temple?

Comment: @Mr.Bond I agree that the angel is Jesus.  I don't have a problem with that.  Jesus is God's messenger to us--the Sent of God.

Comment: TAOTL is one and the same being as God because he is God and there is only one God. He is not the same person of God the Father or God the Holy Spirit. All three persons are distinct from each other within the Godhead who have one and same nature, hence the Trinity.

Comment: @Mr.Bond If TAOTL had been Yahweh, then Jesus and John would have been lying when they said no one had seen or heard God **at any time**.  Technically, per the Hebrew, Jesus, the angels, and perhaps judges among the people, were all "Gods" (Hebrew has no case distinction for "elohim").  So was Jesus "elohim"? Yes. But was he Yahweh, i.e. God the Father Himself? No.  He was Yahweh's messenger, the Son of God.

Comment: The Father has no separate manifestation from the Son. The Son is the only manifestation and revelation of the Father. The Son reveals the Father and to see the Son is to see the essence of the Father. John 1:1, 18, 10:30, 12:45; Colossians 1:15; Hebrews 1:3. Read John 14. Explain Genesis 16:7-13. Also Genesis 17:1-2 which was a "physical" appearance of God. And Genesis 18:1, Genesis 32:30, JUDGES 6-22-23. Acts 7:2, The Lord of glory appeared to our father Abraham at Genesis 11:31, 15:7.  Read all of Acts 7 as Stephen explains who appeared to Moses, at Exodus 3. Please read ALL the references

Comment: @Mr.Bond Your first two sentences are correct.  Your third sentence begins to drift from the truth with the word "essence."  God's essence, or His substance, is not for finite and sinful mortals to even discuss: we are not given this knowledge, and have no comprehension of it.  Gen. 16 refers to the "angel" of Yahweh, not Yahweh himself.  Gen. 17 uses a verb which is not limited to seeing with the natural eyes, and could be translated differently.  In any case, it appears you are seeking for the Bible to contradict itself; and I am not interested in going on this search with you.

Comment: Biblasia I have never heard that sinful mortals are not even to discuss the nature/essence of God? Who told you this? The Jews discussed it at John 10:33. Jesus Himself brought up His deity by quoting Psalms 82:6 at John 10:35-38. And yes, I know He referred to Himself as the Son of God, do you know why?Paul brought it up at Philippians 2:6-9. I also quoted you Isaiah 6:1 and I wrote about it here: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/86545/for-those-who-reject-the-deity-of-jesus-christ-how-do-you-explain-isaiah-seeing Genesis 17:22, when God finished talking with Abram God went up

Comment: @Mr.Bond If Jesus was God, John 1:18 was a lie.  I believe the Bible over human theological inventions.  The Bible's teaching is not that Jesus was God, but that God dwelt in him.  Jesus was our example.  We are to seek God's indwelling presence as well.  If God abides in us, it does not make us God, just as it did not convert Jesus' humanity into deity.  Nowhere in the Bible is God's _substance_ or _essence_ addressed.  His _identity_ is addressed, but not His _substance._  The nearest we come is John 4:24 and Luke 24:39--which, together, tell us that Jesus cannot have been God.

Answer (score 0):

In the KJV of the Bible, in John 1:1 the writer states that the "Word" (Jesus), is God.  Not God the Father, but God nonetheless.  So if Jesus is "God", then it becomes clear that God the Son is who appeared to Moses in the burning bush, as he claimed to be the God of Moses's father and also of Abraham, Isaac and Jacob. And since God the Son is coming back with the voice of the archangel, then he must be the head angel or "agent" of God the Father.  IMHO

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).